# import pyodbc results in DLL load failed with error code 193 on Win7

Tags: python, windows-7, 64-bit, pyodbc

I am running 64-bit Windows 7 and the ActiveState Python 2.5 installation (64-bit version).  I just downloaded and installed the pyodbc 2.1.7 win32 package.  When I run the installer as an admin it proceeds with no problem.  When I run python and try

```
import pyodbc
```

I receive the following error:

> ImportError: DLL load failed with
>   [error code 193](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681382(VS.85).aspx#ERROR_BAD_EXE_FORMAT)

I'm thinking it has to do with having the 64-bit version of ActiveState Python installed.  Do I need to remove that and replace it with the 32-bit ActiveState Python installation?  Would that be the preferred way of doing things until more python packages have 64-bit support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It **shouldn't** be too difficult to build yourself.  I know pyodbc supports 64 bit (I worked with the author a bit adding 64 bit support a couple years ago).  If unzip the source zip, you can run:

```
setup.py bdist_wininst
```

*Of course for Python 2.5, I think you'll need Visual Studio 2003, that's probably a deal-breaker.*  With python>=2.6, you could do it with Visual Studio Express 2008.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I decided to go the route of installing 32-bit python.  I was afraid the pyodbc issue was just the tip of the iceberg and I would be running into other incompatibilities down the road...And you're right, the Visual Studio 2003 req't is a deal-breaker (at least for me) ;)